# Setting Apache to listen in network folder

Tags: apache, windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm setting a new virtual machine (Windows 7) hosted on another Windows 7.

I want to set up an Apache environment in this virtual machine and I want DocumentRoot to be in host machine (so that they go in my schedulled backups and other stuff). WMWare lets you add host shared folders from within a virtual machine as network units, and so I can see them in in windows explorer as **"Z:\myfoldername"** (which is actually a folder of host machine), but when I set Apache DocumentRoot as "Z:\myfoldername" it won't start, I see an error

```
Syntax error on line 178 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot must be a directory
```

(ServerRoot remains in virtual machine)

In host machine I set all permissions to all users...

Is this possible to do? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made Apache run under current user instead of as a Service under Local System as the problem was that Local System didn't have a network unit called Z:.